# How to set the apple web app status bar text color?

Tags: css, web-applications

I'm making a Web application for my iPhone XR and now I have styled the status bar to black translucent. But the text color is changing to white but I want this text color to black. Is that possible with a meta tag, or do you need some CSS or javascript?

Thank you for helping!

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

???

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-text-style" content="black"> // this doesn't work btw it is just something I added for what I want.
```

???

Comment: What is your question title? Can you edit?

Comment: I don't believe that you can style the status bar text by any method. The meta tag allows you to choose from three themes, 'black', 'black-translucent' or 'default'. Apple defines what colour the text should be for each theme.

Comment: That's weird, because I have a white background on my web app, but I have black-translucent as theme but then the text is white so you don't see it.